# using regex in mysql based on middle of string value

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a system that uses personalized URLs (i.e. JohnSmith.MyWebsite.com).  In my database, these values are stored in the "purl" column.

If six months from now, I get another john smith I need to put into my system, I simply add a 1 to his name so that his purl becomes JohnSmith1.MyWebsite.com.

My database has grown so large that checking for this manually is a real time consumer.  So, I'd like to make a quick app where I can enter in names, then check against the database to  return the number I should add onto the end.

How can I use mysql to search if JohnSmith[ANY NUMBER].MyWebsite.com exists while not getting a positive hit on a purl like JohnSmithson1234.MyWebsite.com?

So basically, I need an exact match on the name, and domain, but need to get the latest number used so I can add 1 to it.

Comment: I tried "SELECT purl FROM table_name WHERE purl REGEXP '^johnsmith[0-9].MyWebsite.com'" and it returned the results i was expecting... I'm just not sure how to return ONLY the result with the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server does allow [0-9] to match one digit from 0-9. You might want to use

johnsmith[0-9]%.MyWebsite.com

to allow for more digits (though this would also match something like johnsmith123fooledyou.MyWebsite.com)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't do regex searches like you're asking. However, you can easily do this in the application logic. Do something like this:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE purl LIKE 'JohnSmith%';

Then loop over the results in your app and see if you have anything with numbers the purl column.

Also, you would be well served to downcase everything in the purl column since DNS is case insensitive and MySQL is not. You may have times where johnSmith is being searched for but JohnSmith is in the DB and you will have no results.

EDIT:

Apparently MySQL does allow regex searches. To get the one with the highest number add an "ORDER BY purl DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: That will sort lexicographically, which will rank (for example) `10` before `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional field to your database with the number of times each subdomain is created

for example

```
JohnSmith.MyWebsite.com - 5
```

This would mean that you have to create JohnSmith6.MyWebsite.com, and after you create it, update the field to

```
JohnSmith.MyWebsite.com - 6
```

Or you can do 'order by purl DESC' like other users suggested, but if you use this method, add index to the purl field.